# How do i link the build numbers of sub projects in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have a waterfall model of jobs sequence in Jenkins.

Is there a way to link the build numbers and status of the child job to the main job to get overall status.

eg:

- Project 1 was executed with Build Number 100 and passed
- Project 2 was executed with Build Number 200 from Project 1 and Passed.
- Project 3 was executed with Build Number 300 from Project 2 and **Failed**.

so the overall status for Project 1 with Build # 100 is failed.

Comment: there should be some plugins that do that, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Multi-Job plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

You need to define a multi job view. In multi job view, you can have phases like build phase, test phase, etc.
Each of the phases can have one or more jobs.

If any job inside a phase fails, the start build also gets failed:

[image: Multi Job Plugin usage]

**Another approach**:
If you don't want to mark the starting job as failure and still need to mark it as Good or Bad build, you can also take a look at the Promoted Build plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin

For example, in your example Project 1 starts and triggers Project 2, Project 3.
You can mark Project 1 as "Gold star" only if Project 2 and Project 3 have passed.
You can even take some action at the time of promotion.

Hope this helps.